# Wordpress relation taxonomy posts query not giving desired results

Tags: checkbox, tags, taxonomy, wordpress

I've created a filter using all checkboxes to display particular posts by tag. I want the results of the posts returned to contain all the tags based on the checkbox. I can set the tax_query to relation => 'AND' but it returns nothing if it does not get all the variables. The user should be allowed to check as little or as many tag filters as they would like but the resulting posts should have all the tags. Here is the function that does the processing..

```
function CaseStudiesAjaxFunction() {
global $post;

$advertiser = isset( $_GET["advertiser"] )? $_GET["advertiser"] : '';
$agency = isset( $_GET["agency"] )? $_GET["agency"] : '';
$automotive = isset( $_GET["automotive"] )? $_GET["automotive"] : '';
$education = isset( $_GET["education"] )? $_GET["education"] : '';
$financial = isset( $_GET["financial"] )? $_GET["financial"] : '';
$retail = isset( $_GET["retail"] )? $_GET["retail"] : '';
$travel = isset( $_GET["travel"] )? $_GET["travel"] : '';
$search = isset( $_GET["search"] )? $_GET["search"] : '';
$social = isset( $_GET["social"] )? $_GET["social"] : '';
$smartpath = isset( $_GET["smartpath"] )? $_GET["smartpath"] : '';
$halogen = isset( $_GET["halogen"] )? $_GET["halogen"] : '';
$kenshoo = isset( $_GET["kenshoo"] )? $_GET["kenshoo"] : '';
$techvalidate = isset( $_GET["techvalidate"] )? $_GET["techvalidate"] : '';
$infinityawards = isset( $_GET["infinityawards"] )? $_GET["infinityawards"] : '';

$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 12,
            'tax_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'OR',
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $advertiser
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $agency
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $automotive
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $education
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $financial
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $retail
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $travel
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $search
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $social
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $smartpath
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $halogen
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $kenshoo
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $techvalidate
                                ),
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => $infinityawards
                                )
                        ),
                        array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                                    'field' => 'slug',
                                    'terms' => 'case-studies'
                                )
                        )

        );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<div class="case-study">';
        echo '<div class="case-study-img-container">';
            the_post_thumbnail();
        echo '</div>';
        the_title(); echo '<br>';
        the_tags();
    echo '</div>';
endwhile; endif;
die();
```

}

Comment: the `terms` field needs to be an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using tax_query incorrectly.

My suggestion would be to combine all of these tags into a comma delimited string and then use the tag paramater.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Put your tags into an array to make them easier to handle. Instead of setting the value to a blank string if not set use false instead so they'll be removed by `array_filter()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Implode the elements into a string and then set the tag parameter.

```
$tags = array(
    'advertiser' => isset( $_GET["advertiser"] ) ? $_GET["advertiser"] : false,
    'agency'     => isset( $_GET["agency"] ) ? $_GET["agency"] : false,
);

$tag_string = implode( ',', array_filter( $tags ) );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 12
);

if ( ! empty( $tag_string ) ) {
    $args['tag'] = $tag_string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a much more concise way of doing things. Yet, I'm still not getting the desired query results. For example, if the query gets the tags automotive, local, and halogen then the only resulting posts should be the ones that contain all three. With your code as well as my old one, it gave the posts if they had just one of those tags.

Comment: Oh I think need to implode with a + instead of a ,. I'll try it.

Comment: Pleased to hear you got it working. Your original code had the relation set to 'OR' so I assumed you wanted to get posts in any of the tags rather than all.